# select a field of struct in a generic way

Tags: c, generics

I implement a `bisect find` on this `struct Row`, as you can see, there are two parts that have exactly the same logic behind them. I want to know is there a more clever way to decrease the repeated code.

```
typedef struct Row { 
    int a; 
    int b; 
 } Row; 

/**
 * `rows` is an array 
 * `nrow` is the length of the array
 * `target` is the element to locate
 * `bound` determines the start point and point to begin and end with
 **/
Row bisect_left(const Row *rows, int cnt, int target, int id, Row bound){
    Row range;
    range.a = -1, range.b=-1;
    int ll = bound.a, ul = bound.b;
    if (ul < ll || ul < 0 || ll < 0 || ul > cnt-1 || ll > cnt-1) return range;
    int m = (ul+ll)/2;
    if (id == 1) {
        if (rows[ul].a < target || rows[ll].a > target) return range;
        while (rows[m].a != target && (ll <= ul)){
            if (target < rows[m].a)
                if (ul != m)
                    ul = m;
                else
                    break;
            else
                if (ll != m)
                    ll = m;
                else 
                    break;
            m = (ul+ll)/2;
        }
        if((ll > ul) || (m == ll) || (m==ul)) return range;
        int const flag = m;
        while (rows[m].a == target && m < ul){
            m += 1;
        }
        range.b = rows[m].a != target ? m-1 : m;
        m = flag;
        while (rows[m].a == target && m > ll){
            m -= 1;
        }
        range.a = rows[m].a != target ? m+1 : m;
    }

    if (id == 2){
        if (rows[ul].b < target || rows[ll].b > target) return range;
        while (rows[m].b != target && (ll <= ul)){
            if (target < rows[m].b)
                if (ul != m)
                    ul = m;
                else
                    break;
            else
                if (ll != m)
                    ll = m;
                else 
                    break;
            m = (ul+ll)/2;
        }
        if((ll > ul) || (m == ll) || (m==ul)) return range;
        int const flag = m;
        while (rows[m].b == target && m < cnt-1){
            m += 1;
        }
        range.b = rows[m].b != target ? m-1 : m;
        m = flag;
        while (rows[m].b == target && m > 0){
            m -= 1;
        }
        range.a = rows[m].b != target ? m+1 : m;
    }
    return range;
}
```

The usage of this `bisect_left` if you select `id=1`, you are looking up the array by its first element, likewise `id=2` is to check by its second element. eg: `rows= [(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5)],  target =3, cnt=3, bound = (0, 2)` if `id==1` the result should be `(2,2)`, if `id==2` the resuly should be `(0, 0)`

Comment: I'd ask myself: can I create a relative pointer offset into `Row` from `id`?

Comment: @RichardSitze I'm embarrassed to say that I missed your point, are you saying that I can add a third field to Row. `Row foo`, `foo.x`  can be ` foo.a` or `foo.b` decide by this third field. I don't see how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Aside: `(ul+ll)/2;` --> `ll + (ul-ll)/2;` to avoid `int` overflow with large values.

Comment: Instead of 5 tests, 3 are sufficient. `if (ul < ll || ul < 0 || ll < 0 || ul > cnt-1 || ll > cnt-1) return range;` --> `if (ul < ll || ll < 0 || ul > cnt-1)  return range;`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I appreciate your advice, thanks.

Comment: In terms of memory layout, Row { int a; int b } is equivalent to Row { int val[2]; }.  So casting a row to an array of ints, or to a pointer to an int - which can be indexed, does the trick, something like ((int *)(&row))[idx] . While the accepted answer is cleaner, treating a sequence of int elements as an array is idiomatic for low level C programming -- do document it well.  Or play with unions.  Lots of fun options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `a` and `b` have the same type, redefine `Row` to have an array of two elements instead:

```
typedef struct Row { 
    int val[2]; 
} Row;
```

Then you can index it based on the value of `id`:

```
Row bisect_left(const Row *rows, int cnt, int target, int id, Row bound){
    Row range = { { -1, -1 } };
    int ll = bound.val[0], ul = bound.val[1];
    if (ul < ll || ul < 0 || ll < 0 || ul > cnt-1 || ll > cnt-1) return range;
    int m = (ul+ll)/2;

    if (rows[ul].val[id-1] < target || rows[ll].val[id-1] > target) return range;
    while (rows[m].val[id-1] != target && (ll <= ul)){
        if (target < rows[m].val[id-1])
            if (ul != m)
                ul = m;
            else
                break;
        else
            if (ll != m)
                ll = m;
            else 
                break;
        m = (ul+ll)/2;
    }
    if((ll > ul) || (m == ll) || (m==ul)) return range;
    int const flag = m;
    while (rows[m].val[id-1] == target && m < ul){
        m += 1;
    }
    range.val[1] = rows[m].val[id-1] != target ? m-1 : m;
    m = flag;
    while (rows[m]val[id-1] == target && m > ll){
        m -= 1;
    }
    range.val[0] = rows[m].val[id-1] != target ? m+1 : m;

    return range;
}
```